# Не открывается iframe приложение vk

Tags: android, ios, вконтакте, iframe

Добрый день, Проблема со встроенным приложением `iframe` в вконтакте, приложение открывается в браузере (в том числе в браузере на мобиле), но при попытке открыть с нативного клиента ВК **Android** или **IOS** выдает сообщение

> К сожалению, данное приложение не поддерживает Ваше устройство

Сертификат на домене установлен и валидный, в браузере открывается, ранее таких проблем небыло, флеш не используется, буду благодарен за любую подсказку куда смотреть, в гугле вопрос встречается с разными датами, но решения найти не удалось.

До сегодняшнего дня приложение работало отлично!

Вот само приложение - https://vk.com/app5337911_17081054

Comment: что за iframe? покажите код

Comment: @tcpack4 Отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Ребята обновили API. Теперь нужно выбрать "Встраиваемые приложение - приложения сообществ" и в настройках указать ссылки на основную и мобильные версии.

Comment: Какие ребята? Вы о чём?